# How to load a variable from Jquery AJAX $.get

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables, load

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        var miles = $('#miles').val();
        $.get("thetestsearch.php", 'miles=' + miles, function(data){
            $("#results").html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Instead of loading the entire response into `#results`, how would I load just the variable being processed into `#results`?

Comment: What do you mean by *"just the variable being processed"*?

Comment: are you wanting to load the "miles" into results?  something like $('#results').html( $('#miles').val() )

Comment: The question in the post still needs clarification: _how would I load just the variable being processed into #results?_

Comment: Sorry for not being more direct. I am trying get the value of `miles` and pass it along to "thetestsearch.php". When I load `data` into `#results`, it brings along the entire page with it, when all I want is the variable `miles`.

Comment: @user1093634: So it returns an HTML page? Or some other type of data? How does the variable `miles` relate to the response document?

Comment: I'm confused what do you want ? No one can help you if you don't make yourself clear.

Comment: Until you make it clear what the format of `data` is, nobody can help you other than making wild guesses.  What format is `data`?  HTML page?  legal JSON? XML?  text?  If you don't clarify this, I will vote to close your question as not a valid/answerable question.  To be absolutely clear, post a sample response of `data` so we can see exactly what it is.

Comment: Seems clear that you've lost interest in your own question. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

Use the dot (.) or square bracket ([]) operators.  For example if **data** in your example has a property called **name** or **id**, you can do:

```
$('#results').html(data.name);
```

or

```
$('#results').html(data['id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best answer for you is http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score -1):

does `$("#results").html(data.YourVariable);` work?